# Proof writing question: do I need to state the obvious, after showing the contradiction?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, roots

Suppose $\lambda$ is a root of the polynomial $\mathscr{p}(x).$

Then it must be that "Q" follows, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $\lambda$ cannot be a root of $\mathscr{p}(x)$.

Do I have to state that last sentence?  It sounds a bit redundant.

Or would my proof be a bit incomplete without it?

Thanks,

Comment: It entirely depends on the context. It can never hurt. Sometimes it's necessary for clarity if this is only part of a larger proof, and sometimes it should be understood, like perhaps in this case..

Comment: It's usually best to signal that the proof has ended in some way.  "Thus $\lambda$ cannot be a root of $p(x)$"; "The result follows"; "Therefore I'm right, bitches."  Just something so that the reader feels the proof (or that part of the proof) has ended.

Comment: lolol @Bye_World ... thanks :)

Comment: @MattSamuel, it is indeed part of a larger proof, so I will state the last sentence for clarity.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Bye_World Perhaps math would be a more popular subject in school if students were encouraged to end their proofs in the spirit of your third example.